# A markov chain inequality in Billingsley that should be an equation?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In the section on Markov chains in Billingsley's *Probability and Measure* (3e) we have the following inequality on page 120 in the proof of Theorem 8.3,

$$
\begin{align*}
p_{ji}^{(m)} &= 
P_j([X_m=i] \cap [X_n = j \text{ i.o.}])\\
&\le \sum_{n>m} P_j (X_m = i, X_{m+1} \ne j,\ldots,
X_{n-1} \ne j,X_n=j)
\end{align*}
$$

[Notation: $p_{ji}^{(m)} = P(X_m =i \mid X_0=j)$, $P_j(A) = P(A \mid X_0=j)$.]

My question is regarding the inequality sign on the second line.

$X_n=j$ infinitely often if and only if $X_n=j$ infinitely often for $n>m$. Each such path must hit $j$ for the first time after period $m$ at some finite time $n$. So it seems to me that the events on right-hand side of the second line form a partition of the event on right-hand side of the first line and therefore we must have an equality here.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum on the second line computes the probability that $X_n$ hits $j$ at least once.  If there is a positive probability that $X_n$ hits $j$ at least once but not infinitely often (e.g. if $j$ is transient), then the inequality is strict.